# Can hanger extender be used as replaceable hanger?

Tags: derailleur-hanger, frame-protection

One advantage of replaceable hanger for rear derailleur is that you can replace it (opposite to fixed hanger). I have fixed hanger (or fixed frame) and although it is a steel frame I started wondering if I could add hanger extender as a protection tool.

One point I can see it might fail to protect anything that extender is pretty short (comparing to hanger), it is more solid and there is no really a point where it could bend.

So would it be an overkill (over-protection) and it won't protect anything or is it actually a good idea?

Comment: One option to protect the derailer is to install a derailer guard on the dropout.

Comment: The derailer guard acts as a lever and actually helps to destroy the frame. This is why they haven't been common since the 90s.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, misunderstanding -- I want to protect the frame, not the derailleur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it. There is a good chance that the extender is sturdier than the fixed derailleur hanger, in which case it would add leverage, making a bent or broken hanger even more likely.

Answer (score 2):

No, a hanger extender cannot be used as replaceable hanger for the following reason: a hanger extender is bolted on where the current derailleur is bolted on (in the current hanger thus) allowing the derailleur to be bolted on even lower.

Thus, a hanger extender extends the current hanger (fixed or attached).

If you want to protect yourself against the damage of the current hanger simply be careful. And before you damage your hanger take the measurements of it or try to find a replaceable hanger that may fit your dropout. And once your fixed hanger is damaged simply cut it off and put the replacement.

Comment: Thank you but just a clarification, I didn't mean a replacement as 1:1 change of parts, I meant using it as protection tool, in the same sense as the hanger was "detached" from the frame (creating replaceable  hanger) to protect it.

Comment: You mean like a circuit breaker (a fuse) in an electric circuit? Adding a weaker part so it breaks instead of the fixed hanger? One question - is it a road bike or mountain/gravel (rough terrain) bike?

Comment: Mike, exactly, like a fuse. It is a gravel bike with mounted MTB rear derailleur.